# Automatically change from admob test ad id to proper banner ad id generating signed apk

Tags: android, admob

I was wondering if there is a way to change from admob test ad id to proper banner ad id automatically when generating signed apk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set id in code like that:

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    //use test id
} else {
    //use production id
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From my experience whenever I debug in emulator I see test ads but when deployed I see live ads - that is with latest admob version.

But I guess you can do something like check debug and set test ad otherwise set it to live ads:

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
  // do something for a debug build
}
```